# Ubuntu 12.04: Problem running "apt-get upgrade"

Tags: apt, upgrade, package-management, dpkg, dependencies

While trying to update ubuntu
I am facing this problem, don't much idea how to address this?

```
E: dpkg was interrupted, you must manually run 'sudo dpkg --configure -a' to correct the problem.
root@server1:/home/pawan# sudo dpkg --configure -a
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of libssl-dev:
 libssl-dev depends on libssl1.0.0 (= 1.0.1-4ubuntu5.38); however:
  Version of libssl1.0.0 on system is 1.0.1-4ubuntu5.36.
dpkg: error processing libssl-dev (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
Errors were encountered while processing:
 libssl-dev
root@server1:/home/pawan#
```

As per the answer I ran the command but faced with this problem.

```
pawan@server1:~$ sudo apt-get install libssl1.0.0 openssl
[sudo] password for pawan: 
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
libssl1.0.0 is already the newest version.
The following packages will be upgraded:
  openssl
1 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 31 not upgraded.
1 not fully installed or removed.
Need to get 0 B/524 kB of archives.
After this operation, 0 B of additional disk space will be used.
Do you want to continue [Y/n]? y
E: Internal Error, No file name for libssl1.0.0
pawan@server1:~$ sudo apt -f install libssl-dev
sudo: apt: command not found
pawan@server1:~$ sudo apt-get -f install libssl-dev
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
libssl-dev is already the newest version.
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 32 not upgraded.
1 not fully installed or removed.
After this operation, 0 B of additional disk space will be used.
Do you want to continue [Y/n]? y
E: Internal Error, No file name for libssl1.0.0
pawan@server1:~$
```

Comment: What happens if you run `sudo dpkg --configure -a --force-all` and then `sudo apt-get -f install` ?

Comment: I haven't tried that, it that ok to run that command?

Comment: Yes of course.  It should force the installation to continue.

Answer (score 1):

Open terminal and type :

```
 sudo apt -f install libssl-dev

 sudo apt update
```

If it doesn't work :

```
   sudo apt-get install --reinstall libssl-dev
```

Comment: Emad Arshad Alam - I updated the question with the output of the command you suggest.

Comment: Install synaptic package manager and remove everything related to 'libssl' which is installed on your system. Now, again using synaptic package manager install the following packages "libssl-dev","libssl-doc","libssl1.00" and "libssl1.00:386".These are the packages installed in my PC related to libssl. Ask if you don't get anything.

Comment: @Emad Arshad Alam dont use words like try,this should...in answer if you aren't sure post it as comment instead!

Comment: @minigeek I research for the problem when all the hit and trial methods have failed. That's why my answers include "try" because there still was window for the trial method open. Since, the guy didn't reply I didn't change my answer. But, anyways I'll keep your suggestion in mind.